# Zebra TLP2844 Windows 7 USB escape issue

Tags: c#, .net, printing, zebra-printers

I am on Windows 7 32bit running the latest drivers from Zebra and printing via USB to the TLP2844.  I am trying to generate a set of labels and print them to the label printer from C# using the RawPrinterHelper class as mentioned in numerous posts online.  If I power the printer up and use the oM command which is to disable the initial Esc sequence feed then it works perfectly and prints the two labels correctly.  Thereafter the height appears to be incorrect because instead of printing two labels it prints one label with the second piece of text towards to bottom of the label.  Any help would be appreciated.

Label Dimensions: 
Width: 75mm
Height: 34mm
Gap: 3mm

Example command sequence being sent to the printer:

```
oM

N
q599
Q272,024
ZT
S2       
A253,26,0,3,1,1,N,"TEST LABEL TEXT"
P1

N
q599
Q272,024
ZT
S2       
A253,26,0,3,1,1,N,"TEST LABEL2 TEXT"
P1
```

Comment: I have some old notes on this that I will try to dig up later tonight.  In the mean time, best of luck.  Those printers never seem to work, even with everything correct!

Comment: I've worked with Zebra enough to know that nearly any other option is better.  Good luck :\

Comment: Can you post a full sequence of commands you are sending to the printer on the wire, to see if you are missing anything.

Comment: Why are you using the oM command, you are sending raw commands, not using the windows driver so I see no need for it?

Comment: I am sending the raw commands to the USB interface where the printer is attached and from what I understand in the EPL manual I needed to send this command through when using the Windows driver.  My problem is that it works perfectly for the first print after turning the printer on and thereafter it does not.  The test code is based on info in this article http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/sending-raw-epl2-directly-to-a-zebra-lp2844-via-c

Comment: The article never uses the oM command (for good reason). try dropping it and see if your code works.

Comment: If you are not ever going to print from a application (say word or notepad) and only print from your code to your printer I recommend just setting it to the Generic/Text Only driver built in to windows.

Comment: I added the oM command because the example does not work.  It prints the text for both labels on the same label.  I even tried increasing the height of the label in an attempt to push the text onto the next label without success.  The oM command was the only thing that got it to print correctly but only if you reset the printer before trying to print.  This is obviously not a workable option.

Comment: Tried installing the generic/text driver and removed the oM command but unfortunately I get the same result.  When the printer is first turned on it prints the two labels correctly but if I print them again it prints the two on the same label.  If I set the height bigger than it should be then the alignment goes all wrong but the labels are still not printed correctly.

Comment: Try it without the Q and without the oM. Also make sure the newline after your last P1 is getting sent down the line.

Comment: Nope that did not work but if I print four lines of text it works correctly.  Anything less than that and it is wrong.  Guessing it is something with Windows 7 Pro and the printer interface.

Answer (score 1):

As you are disabling the detection of the top of a label the most likely culprit is your `Q272,024` is not large enough. As you have not posted too much extra info I am not sure why you are using the `oM` command from your example it does not seem necessary.

---

Try omitting the `Q` and the `oM` the device should be smart enough to be able to feed correctly on it's own. (make sure you have done a reset to make sure you cleared out any previous `oM`'s you may have sent) Also make sure you are in line mode and not page mode.

---

Here is a few classes i wrote up to convert from Inches or mm to dots I wrote for internal company use.

```
 public static partial class Convert
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts number of dots in to millimeters in length
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dots">length in dots</param>
        /// <returns>length in millimeters</returns>
        public static float DotsToMm(int dots)
        {
            return dots * 0.125125f;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts millimeters to dots in length.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mm">length in millimeters</param>
        /// <returns>length in dots</returns>
        public static int MmToDots(float mm)
        {
            return (int)(mm / 0.125125f);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts number of dots in to inches in length
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dots">length in dots</param>
        /// <returns>length in inches</returns>
        public static float DotsToInches(int dots)
        {
            return dots * 0.0049125f;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts inches to dots in length.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mm">length in inches</param>
        /// <returns>length in dots</returns>
        public static int InchesToDots(float Inches)
        {
            return (int)(Inches / 0.0049125f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the conversion classes.  I did the calculation manually but these are more useful in the long run.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the mode between line (OEPL1) or paged mode made no difference.  Leaving out the page size also did not help.  The only thing that has worked so far is to ensure 4 lines of text are printed out and that there is text in the last line printed.

Comment: @Fireclaw, I have run out of ideas, I wish I could help you more. I really dug in to the EPL stuff about a year ago but I am a bit rusty now, I am not sure what is causing the problem. The only other thing I can think of is, is the text that is being printed too long and it is doing weird things with the print buffer?

Answer (score 0):

The driver sends down an initialization sequence which may be screwing up your labels.  Can you capture the output of the driver by pointing it to a file and seeing what the driver is sending down? You can play with the driver settings to make sure they are correct